# Array of JSON objects loaded from files

Tags: javascript, json

I have a set of files a.json, b.json, c.json, etc., and I want to load the data contained therein to a single data structure in JavaScript. However, the last line of the following code always returns 0 instead of 3 which I expect. What am I doing wrong?

```
    files = ["a", "b", "c"];
    var dataset = [];

    function getObject(file) {
        return $.getJSON(file).then(function (data) {
            return data;
        });
    }


    for (i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        getObject(files[i] + ".json").done(function (data) {
            dataset.push(data);
        });
    }

    alert(dataset.length)
```

Comment: Look into asynchronicity and the concept of promises/deferred objects. You're alerting before the loads have completed because the load actions as asynchronous. The code does not pause to enact them.

Comment: [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: [Wait until all jquery ajax request are done?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709597/wait-until-all-jquery-ajax-request-are-done)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if run your `alert` immediately after the calls to `$.ajax` return, the data isn't available and your variable hasn't been set. You have to wait until done is called (which is long after the method call to `$.ajax` returns, [since it's asynchronous](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests)). [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Second, to synchronize requests, you can use [`$.when`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) so you're notified when all requests resolve. [Wait until all jQuery Ajax requests are done?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709597/wait-until-all-jquery-ajax-request-are-done)

```
var files = ["a", "b", "c"];
var dataset = [];
var requests = [];

for (i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    requests.push($.getJSON(files[i] + ".json") );
}

// $.when may not take the requests as an array, in that case use
// $.when.apply($, requests).done();
$.when(requests).done(function() {
    for (var i=0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        dataset.push(arguments[i]);
    }
    alert('All three received, dataset length is ' + dataset.length)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could handle it in the `done` method:

```
var doneCount = 0;
for (i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    getObject(files[i] + ".json").done(function (data) {
        dataset.push(data);
        if ( ++doneCount  == files.length ){
           alert(dataset.length);
        }
    });

}
```